# How to handle Err.Number in ASP?

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm really struggling with handling errors in ASP.

I have a script that is sending out emails from a MS SQL database where it gets email address and the actual mail itself.

The script loops through the addresses, sending 50 at a time so as not to block the queue.

The problem is that whenever there is an invalid or illegal email address the sending stops and the page returns a 500 error.

So I added the On Error Resume Next tag and now it seems that instead it sends out duplicate emails.

I'm not sure how to resolve this but it seems it sends sometimes 2 or sometimes 3 emails to each address. As t seems to resend to already sent mails when the page number updates or it seems to send ther first 50 on page 1 then the first 100 on page 2 then the first 150 on page 3 instead of sending 0-50 on page 1, 51-100 on page 2, 101 - 150 on page 3 etc etc.

Naturally I just want one email to each address and not to stop when there's an email with an email address in the database.

Would really appreciate some hlpe as I've been going mental now for the past 6 hours trying to place If Err.Number at different places in the code without success.

Thanks for any and all help guys.

```
<% On Error Resume Next
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Buffer=FALSE
Server.ScriptTimeout = 36000 

set cn = createobject("adodb.connection")
cn.open strCon
set rs = cn.execute("select * from mails where mailID = "& request.querystring("mailID") &"") 
    subject = rs("subject")
    mailType = rs("mailType")
    mailBody =  rs("mailBody")

    set rs = cn.execute("Select * from settings")
    strServer = rs("server")
    email = rs("email")

    page = trim(request.querystring("page"))
    If page = "" Then
    page = 1
    else
    page = cint(page)
    End If
    DisplayNum = 0

    Set oCon = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Rec = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
    oCon.Open straCon
    Rec.PageSize = 50
    Rec.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    sql = "Select email from dbo.emailTables where emailID Between '1' and '5000'"      
    Rec.Open sql, oCon

    ipage = Rec.PageCount   

    if page = 0 or page > ipage Then
    Rec.AbsolutePage = ipage
    else
    Rec.AbsolutePage = page
    end if

    allEmail = Rec.RecordCount 

    do while not Rec.eof AND DisplayNum < 50

    If Err.Number = 0 Then

    Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update     
    ObjSendMail.To = Rec("email")
    ObjSendMail.Subject = subject
    ObjSendMail.From = sender
    ObjSendMail.CreateMHTMLBody "http://www.urlpage.com"
    ObjSendMail.Send     
    Set ObjSendMail = Nothing       
    DisplayNum = DisplayNum + 1         
    Rec.movenext

    Err.Clear
    End If          

    loop

    If ipage > 1 And page < ipage Then
    strPage = "post.asp?mailID="& request.querystring("mailID")&"&page="& page+1
    strTimer = 30

    else
    strPage = "overview.asp"
    strTimer = 5
    strMsg = strMsg & "<br><br>All mails sent to list. "

    end if
```

%>

```
<head>
<title>Newsletter</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="<%=strTimer%>; URL=<%=strPage%>">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code so that you only trap for errors on sending of the email. As it is now, any errors anywhere in this code will be bypassed and you won't know if there are errors other than sending the email. If you change your code to the following it will only skip errors relating to sending the email.

```
<% 'On Error Resume Next '---removed
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Buffer=FALSE
Server.ScriptTimeout = 36000 

set cn = createobject("adodb.connection")
cn.open strCon
set rs = cn.execute("select * from mails where mailID = "& request.querystring("mailID") &"") 
    subject = rs("subject")
    mailType = rs("mailType")
    mailBody =  rs("mailBody")

    set rs = cn.execute("Select * from settings")
    strServer = rs("server")
    email = rs("email")

    page = trim(request.querystring("page"))
    If page = "" Then
    page = 1
    else
    page = cint(page)
    End If
    DisplayNum = 0

    Set oCon = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
    Set Rec = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Recordset")
    oCon.Open straCon
    Rec.PageSize = 50
    Rec.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    sql = "Select email from dbo.emailTables where emailID Between '1' and '5000'"      
    Rec.Open sql, oCon

    ipage = Rec.PageCount   

    if page = 0 or page > ipage Then
    Rec.AbsolutePage = ipage
    else
    Rec.AbsolutePage = page
    end if

    allEmail = Rec.RecordCount 

    do while not Rec.eof AND DisplayNum < 50

    'If Err.Number = 0 Then '---removed

    Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update     
    ObjSendMail.To = Rec("email")
    ObjSendMail.Subject = subject
    ObjSendMail.From = sender
    ObjSendMail.CreateMHTMLBody "http://www.urlpage.com"
    On Error Resume Next '---added
    ObjSendMail.Send     
    On Error Goto 0 '---added
    Set ObjSendMail = Nothing       
    DisplayNum = DisplayNum + 1         
    Rec.movenext

    'Err.Clear '---removed
    'End If '---removed         

    loop

    If ipage > 1 And page < ipage Then
    strPage = "post.asp?mailID="& request.querystring("mailID")&"&page="& page+1
    strTimer = 30

    else
    strPage = "overview.asp"
    strTimer = 5
    strMsg = strMsg & "<br><br>All mails sent to list. "

    end if
%>
```

Comment: Very useful John, thanks for helping me understand the Error function.

Comment: It seems to trap the error as you say but it's not gotten me any closer to resolving the problem. I added a delay timer to the code thinking that maybe it could be because too many emails were getting sent to the queue at once...but this was not the problem as I reduced page size to just 5 and page update to 30 seconds and if SMTP Server can't send 5 emails in 30 seconds then...really Microsoft what's the point? ;)

Comment: So I'm still stuck. Every email seems to get sent 3 times and since there's no Loop on getting email address. Ie. the DO LOOP function is only getting the next records (.movenext), and not looping itself...I'm not sure where this repeated sending is coming from?

Comment: Looking through the code I can't see a reason. Do you have access to web server logs to see exactly what the requests for this script are?